# Why does the number of printed digits differ between systems?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, llvm

I'm on OS X with `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)` and on Windows 7 with `gcc (tdm64-1) 4.6.1`.

Why does the following code generates a different output on both systems:

```
double d = 2.71828152557319224769116772222332656383514404296875;
printf("%1.55f\n", d);
```

OS X output is `2.7182815255731922476911677222233265638351440429687500000`

Win7 output is `2.7182815255731922000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

`sizeof(double) == 8` on both systems.

Comment: For the record, Wikipedia says Euler's constant begins with 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995. That differs after 2.7182818. Apparently you converted a single-precision value to double, then used the result as a literal.

Comment: Nope. It's meant to be an approximation.

Comment: OK. I don't have a Windows system to test on, but I would guess that you can print additional digits by casting the number to `long double`. `printf("%1.55Lf\n", (long double) d);` This still won't get you 55 digits, though. You might also try the hex format conversion `%a`, which is the most practical way to exactly represent floating-point values, as long as all receiving platforms support it. (Of course, relying on rounding works just fine.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter This is even worse... Just displays 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 no matter what d is... I don't think Microsoft did a good job implementing the C standard library...

Comment: Did you remember to add the `L` in `%Lf`?

Comment: Yes. Even if I didn't, it should at least output nonsense and generate a compiler warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard does not require that `printf` print the actual value, only that it be right up to a certain number of places and satisfy certain rounding-direction error constraints. Most unix-like operating systems print the exact value, or the value correctly rounded to the requested number of places if there are not enough places to print the exact value. MSVCRT rounds to a fixed number of places and pads the rest with zeros. Both behaviors are conforming, but the latter is really ugly and low-quality.

Comment: So it depends on the standard library used? How do I generate a more precise output on Windows systems?

Comment: @Max that should be another question. Probably you need to implement your own algorithm by multiplying by 10 and getting the integer part. But note that Windows did already print all the meaningful digits. The rest are just noise from the inherent imprecision of floating-point numbers.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Multiplying by 10 and getting the integer part does not work. It will give the wrong answer. And the rest of the digits are **not** noise. As you can see in OP's example, they're exact.

Comment: @MaxRied: Indeed. If you want to generate the exact output on windows, you have to find or write an implementation yourself. It's not terribly hard, but also not entirely trivial. Basically you have to convert the mantissa to a (simplified) decimal bignum and do bignum arithmetic on it to apply the exponent.

Comment: For one possible approach, you can see my implementation here. It's the smallest/simplest I know of that's capable of printing the exact value. http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vfprintf.c

Comment: @R.. No, he happened to use an excessively precise literal matching the exact FP value. The result would be the same if he changed digits after the 17th. Windows printed 17 digits which is what `double` gets you. And naively multiplying by 10 "recovers" the extra digits from Windows' output: https://ideone.com/eyUFiA

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The value is an exact number. It's not "excessively precise". Whether it's close to the value of *e* and whether you think it's intended to serve as *e* is irrelevant; it's still an exact number. The naive multiply-by-10 loop implementation only works for values with small positive exponents. It does not work for negative exponents, in which case multiplication by 10 is a lossy operation, in general.

Comment: @R.. Just had a look at C11 standard §7.21.6.1. From understanding it requires the printf-function to print the exact value as it does not mention anything about the precision at all.

Comment: @R.. Obviously my program won't work for numbers greater than or equal to 10. And obviously it generates all the digits in OP's literal despite not having them as input. That means that the digits at the end of OP's literal represent precision in excess of what is actually used, which may be misleading to readers of the source code. I would call that excess precision. It would be more informative to use a literal with *different* trailing numbers for this particular illustration. If the type were `long double`, the story would be different.

Comment: Your algorithm works for values in the range [0.5,10). It does not work in general for smaller values.

Comment: OK, back you your point. Let's consider another example that's not an approximation of *e* to get rid of the spurious notion of approximation. I'm going to use `double x = 0.000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625;` This is an exact number; it's 2 raised to the -48 power. You could probably also write it as `0.0000000000000035527136788005` and get the same value, but this doesn't mean the former has "excess precision"; rather, it means the latter is a sufficiently-good approximation to the exact value of the former to translate to the same double-precision value.

Comment: Yes. But without an explicit note as to why there are twice as many digits as necessary, and that the digits represent the actual value of the resulting object, I would assume that the author is ignorant about FP and ignore them. Those digits are effectively ignored by the compiler and amount to a source code comment.

Comment: This is no production code, I wrote it too demonstrate my problem. Besides, what is the downside of specifying more digits than useful. It's ok for documentation purpose and you don't know what changes in future versions of the C standard will happen.

Comment: @MaxRied It depends what you want to document. Specifying numbers only to the machine's precision helps reveal what the output precision might be and what numbers it's actually working with. Comments are nice but I prefer them to be restricted to inside `/* */`. Numeric precision is all but independent of C; it's platform-specific but usually you get the IEEE spec.

Comment: Note that while this doesn't seem to apply to source-level literals, there is a real reason to write exact values when you mean it. `strtod("0.000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625", 0)` should return 0x1p-48 without raising any exceptions. On the other hand, `strtod("0.0000000000000035527136788005", 0)` should raise the inexact exception.